# Firefox prevents me from opening Tor

Tags: firefox

A few days ago I suddenly lost the use of Firefox and Tor. The computer store I went to eventually got Firefox back and deleted Tor. I've reinstalled Tor, but when I try to open Tor I get a message:

firefox.exe - application.exe The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000022). Click OK to closed the application. I've spent an hour on the Firefox 'help' page but couldn't get through to them. Can anyone here help me to run both Firefox and Tor?